# How to shorten function in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to shorten a function in Codeigniter such as:

```
$this->lang->line('hello', FALSE);
```

Above function returns string and fetches a single translation line from the already loaded language files, based on the line’s name.

How to make it shorter like:

```
$line['hello']
```

or probably

```
$line->hello
```

Appreciate helps! Thanks!! :)

Comment: Just load language helper & you can access these using a function named lang() ``$this->load->helper('language');``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function in helpers file like:

```
function lang(){
   return $this->lang->line('hello', FALSE);
}
```

Call this like:

```
echo lang();
```

Comment: This function is already present in language_helper file, there's no need to re-create it, he just have to load the helper file.

Comment: @ahmad just an example . no idea about CI LANG LIB. Bhai.

Comment: @ahmad my bad, I didn't realize that there's already such function, thanks. But thanks anyway to @devpro for his suggestion, it did solve my problem but I need to change `$this` to `$ci` to make it works.

Comment: @alvian-casablancas happy to help u friend.. Best of luck for the future

Comment: Yes u need to change the instance. If it help u don't forget to accept the answer.. @alvian-casablancas

Answer (score 0):

There is already a pre-defined Codeigniter function "lang()" in language helper, no need to make function of your own.

```
echo $this->lang->line('hello');
```

is equal to

```
echo lang('hello');
```

Also it's useful in creating form label like:

```
echo lang('language_key', 'form_item_id');

//becomes <label for="form_item_id">language_key</label>
```

Thanks.